# Using custom dll in Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, dll, shared-libraries, dllimport

First, my compiler and OS:

- Qt Creator 1.3
- Qt 4.6 (32 bit)
- Windows 7 Ultimate

I want to learn how to create and import a dll in Qt. I've created a `*.dll` file using Qt Creator, called `Shared1.dll` which contains nothing but an empty class named `Shared1`. Now I'd like to use `Shared1` class in another Qt project. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25870-How-to-load-DLL(C-C-)-in-Qt-on-Windows) link.

Comment: The information is not enough. I cannot load a library with QLibrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Pro file to include your header files and libraries..

For Header Files:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Source\HeaderFiles"
```

For libraries:

```
LIBS += "C:\Source\Libraries\MyLib.lib"
```

Include those header files while using the functions from the libraries.

This works for me... Try it..

Comment: Instead give LIBS += "C:\Source\Libraries\MyDll.dll"

Comment: @liaK `LIBS += -LD:/Projects/Restauro/Library/ -lLibrary` works in my case but your version is not working. Useful [link](http://mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)