# How to add an ActiveX control to Qt form from custom DLL

Tags: qt, dll, activex

Well, I'm trying to achieve the following: add and ActiveX control (AxExpressViewerDll::AxCExpressViewerControl from AutoDesk) to a Qt form. But, there is no way to get the object to load from DLL, for example (the long number is the UUID taken from Visual Studio):

```
QAxWidget* wmp = new QAxWidget();
wmp->setControl("{55523A67-A054-4064-B88D-0070305C9F95}");
```

VS picks up the COM object fine, the .dll (AdView.dll) was registered with regsvr32, I even linked the dll directly to the project with the LIBS directive. I even tried this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790611/using-custom-dll-in-qt-application)

I always get:

> CoCreateInstance failure (Class not
> registered)
>
> QAxBase::setControl:
> requested control
> {55523A67-A054-4064-B88D-0070305C9F95}
> could not be instantiated

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You might try instantiating the control by it's name. Also, check if you don't need to pass a license file for the control in the constructor.

Comment: Ok, and how do you get the control's name? I don't have any docs available. All I have is a small amount of example code where the component is used in C# in VS ...

Answer (score 0):

answsered after months, but still might be helpful :

Maybe you should take  look at the qtbrowser plugin : http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/

Instead of developing and ActiveX and then embedding it into qt, use directly qt. Unless you want your activeX to be available outside qt...